# Using PyEZ on EX4300

Tags: pyez

Does PyEZ work with an EX4300 switch?

Looking https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/rest-api-overview.html under the Platform and Release Support link, it appears that EX series switches do not support the REST API. Does PyEZ use REST to talk with the switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyEZ makes netconf session to devices over SSH/Telnet/Serial connection. Check below link for more details

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-pyez/topics/task/program/junos-pyez-connection-methods.html#id-connection-methods-overview

You can use PyEZ to connect to any of EX device and get back output in XML/JSON.

Answer (score 0):

PyEZ is supported on all the devices which have the Junos version 11.4 or above and it must be able to accept NETCONF over SSH connections.
PyEZ relies on it, through the [ncclient](https://github.com/ncclient/ncclient).

```
root@r1_re# show system services
netconf {
    ssh;
}
```

[image]